# If every subsequence ${a_{sn}}$ where $s>1$ is an integer converges , Then will $a_{n} $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If every subsequence ${a_{sn}}$ where $s>1$ is an integer converges , Then will $a_{n} $ converge?

I have an idea ..
If I have to prove that $a_{n}$ is convergent ,proving that it is a cauchy sequence will be enough.. $|a_{n+m}-a_n|< \epsilon$. Now take $m=nk$ and then vary $k$.will that work?

Answer (score 6):

No. Take $a_p=p$ where $p$ is prime and $a_n=0$ for $n$ composite. Any subsequence $a_{sn}$ has at most one prime index. Hence, it is nonzero for a finite number of terms.

Comment: How can any subsequence $a_{sn}$ have at most one prime.index?

Comment: Your idea is fine, but no TA would accept your post as a  proof of anything. It's written so carelessly.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Really? This former TA would gladly accept it.

Comment: @AyanBiswas Hint: Suppose $a_{sn}$ has a prime index. Then $sn=p$ is prime for some $n$. ($s$ is already chosen with $s>1$.) This means $s$ or $n$ must be one. But $s$ cannot be 1. So $n=1$ and $s=p$ is prime. Now if there is another prime $q$, we have $sn=pn=q$, which implies $n=1$ and hence $p=q$.